# ClassNotFoundException org.odfclown.files.File

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pdfclown

I´m using Maven and Spring MVC to create a webapp. When building with Maven the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pdfclown.files.File
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:612)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In my Build path I have already imported the pdfclown.jars. Is it possbible that this error occurs because I´m using the "standard" SpringDispatcher in my WebAppInitializer?

```
    public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

Controller
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(AppContextConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        // UtF8 Charactor Filter.
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you also added the maven war plugin to your plugins (if you don’t use spring boot, if you use spring boot you need to add their spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin)?

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
   <configuration>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve the problem! I tried to add the plugin but it does not work in this context